# drop-down navigation menu with HTML PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, menu, drop-down-menu

***EDIT*** FIXED by user @jeroen
You have to move the li and a tags inside the while loop.

Thank you for this, F4LLCON

So the final code (not so clean, but works now):

```
<?php   
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `apps` ");
while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
?>
<li>
<?php
$meer = $query_row['TITLE'];
$desc_inject = '';
$sub_string = substr($desc_inject, 0, 200);                             
echo $sub_string." " . '' . '<a href="applink.php?id='.$query_row["ID"].'">' . $meer . '</a>';
?>
</li>
<br />
<?php
}
?>
```

I want a drop-down menu that will show the TITLES out of my MySQL database.
I know how to do everything concerning the ID etc.

The only problem is that the PHP version of the drop-down menu will SELECT all the TITLES in my database and parse it as ONE link.

So instead of

```
Home
>About
>Contact
>Another
```

it will look like

```
Home
>About
 Contact
 Another
```

With other words

```
Home
>About Contact Another
```

It will not make multiple drop-down links but only one drop-down link

If you for example do:

```
<div>
<?php
echo $query_row['TITLE'];
?>
</div>
```

It will make a individual `<div></div>` for every TITLE in my database, so I thought this method would also work for the drop-down links..

Does anybody know how to fix it so it will make individual `<li></li>` for every TITLE?

Here is a normal drop-down menu:

```
<li id="media"><a href=""></a> 
    <ul>
    <li id="1a"><a href="">About</a></li> 
    <li id="1b"><a href="">Contact</a></li> 
    <li id="1b"><a href="">Another</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>
```

And here is the PHP drop-down menu:

```
<li id="media"><a href=""></a> 
<ul>
<li>
<a href="">
<?php   
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `apps` ");
while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
echo $query_row['TITLE'];
?>
<br />
<?php
}
?>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the `li` and `a` tags inside the `while` loop.

```
echo '<li><a href="">' . $query_row['TITLE'] . '</a></li>';
```

Comment: Oh I see, I will try it out now.

Edit
Awesome tip! Another thing learned :)

I will mark this as 'answer' when the time (8min) is up and I can mark it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
<li id="media"><a href=""></a> 
<ul>
<?php   
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `apps` ");
while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
 echo "<li><a href=''>" . $query_row['TITLE'] ."</a></li>";
}
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: This worked but changed the design.

This worked:
<?php 
          `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `apps` ");
          while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
          {
         ?>
                                    <li><a href="">
                                    <?php
           echo $query_row['TITLE'];
         ?>
                                    </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <br />
         <?php
          }`
         ?>

Comment: Why you adding "<br />" after <li>?
As a spacer? It would be better to use margins or paddings on li element.

Comment: It works this way, when I copy/paste your code into my code, it did change it to individual links, but all the links moved to the right for almost 100px, and the first link was moved for almost 50px; so I am good with the code I have. I added it to my question, thanks anyways